# How to create a date range with php?

Tags: php, date, web

I tried to make time with PHP. start date of 2017-01-29 to 2017-12-29. But that happened I could not print in February because the month maximum of only 28 days. How to order printed anyway but with the February date up to 28.

my script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Start date
$date = '2017-01-29';
// End date
$end_date = '2017-12-29';

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo "$date\n";
    echo "<br>";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: https://www.rarst.net/code/php-date-range/   OR  https://boonedocks.net/blog/2007/01/08/Creating-a-Date-Range-Array-with-PHP.html

Comment: So the `+1 month` is adding next 30 days or how many days in the base date?

Comment: use dateperiod `$period = new DatePeriod($date, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end_date);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Date Range, Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186858/php-date-range-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the DateTime class to find the last day of next month:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Start date
$date = '2017-01-29';
// End date
$end_date = '2017-12-29';

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
            echo "$date\n"; 
            echo "<br>";
            $d = new DateTime( $date );
            $d->modify( 'last day of next month' );
            $date = $d->format( 'Y-m-d' );
}
```

Now this may not be fully what you're interested in since you might want to try different start dates and have it not go to the end of the next month or you might want it to use 2/28 for the February date, but then go back to the 29th for each successive month. But this should get you closer to the logic you are needing. I think using DateTime will be part of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the March reaches 31 days and I want to keep the March 29 date is not changed to the last day of the month. :(

Comment: I agree so you could just add an if condition where you only use the 'last day of the month' check if the new month bled over into the next month.

Comment: Is there really need of using `DateTime`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
    <?php 
         $from = new DateTime;
         $to = new DateTime('+1 year');

        for($date=clone $from; $date<$to; $date->modify('+1 day')){
              echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
         }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason for down voting? Try this code and then vote

Comment: Ya this one buddy!  :D

Comment: I didn't done this, can you explain how this code is working?

Comment: My code will give the output of dates from today's current date to 1-year date. If you want to specific date you can do that.

Comment: But this code is written this show each day not the months date right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145863/discussion-between-pradeep-singh-and-itzmukeshy7).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach you can try where you don't have to use `DateTime`.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    // Start date
    $date = '2017-01-29';
    // End date
    $end_date = '2017-12-29';

    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        echo "$date\n"; 
        echo "<br>";
        $date = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("+30 day", strtotime($date)));
    }
```

Using `strtotime("+30 day", strtotime($date)`, you can add 30 days to the current date and get the last date of the month with `t`.

```
    2017-01-29 
    2017-02-28 
    2017-03-31 
    2017-04-30 
    2017-05-31 
    2017-06-30 
    2017-07-31 
    2017-08-31 
    2017-09-30 
    2017-10-31 
    2017-11-30
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
date ("Y-m-t", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($date)));
```

instead of this to get last day of the month

```
date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: This still won't produce the results he is looking for. It skips over February and outputs 2017-3-31 as the second date.