# insert into table using input with start date and end date PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to insert date with range of date using of inputs

here is what i got in HTML

```
<input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate"/> //ex. value="2018-12-18"
<input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate"/> //ex. value="2018-12-31"
```

my PHP code is

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))//this is my submit button
{
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate']
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate']

    $query = "INSERT INTO appointment (date) VALUES (//i want to insert all covered date from start to end)";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

my database table is column is id(auto increment) date and schedule.
how can i input the date from "2018-12-18 to 2018-12-31 in row"

i want my output in my table like this:

```
|   date   |
|2018-12-18|
|2018-12-19|
|2018-12-20|
|2018-12-21| //so on and so fort until reach the end date
```

Comment: You can iterate over each date within the range and insert each with separate queries. There might be a way to do it all in one SQL query, though.

Comment: Why not just have the start and end date as 2 columns? https://3v4l.org/HdCQW could work i guess..

Comment: @user3783243 how can i remove automatic +1day to start time

Comment: Not sure what you mean, which date should be removed? Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365151/how-to-create-a-date-range-with-php

Answer (score -1):

This is taken from another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312630/3923626).

You could take a look at the DatePeriod class:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime($_POST['startdate']),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime($_POST['enddate'])
);
```

Which should get you an array with DateTime objects.

To iterate

```
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
    //$value->format('Y-m-d')       
}
```

You can do it in one query like so:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO appointment (date) VALUES";
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
     $date = $value->format('Y-m-d');
      $query .= "('$date'),";       
}
```

Which gives you:

```
INSERT INTO appointment (date) VALUES('2010-10-01'),('2010-10-02'),('2010-10-03'), 
('2010-10-04'),
```

You might have to delete the final comma.

```
$query = rtrim($query, ',');
```

Comment: can't delete final comma? how?

Comment: @KielDred Show the `rtrim` usage.

Comment: $x = rtrim($date,',');

Comment: @KielDred Doesn't reproduce, https://3v4l.org/uBjPP. Do you use `$x` later?